# How to avoid postback with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Content of my page is:

> ```
> <form id="form1" runat="server">
>     <div>
>         <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
>          <asp:Button ID="btnTransfer" runat="server" Text="Transfer" OnClientClick="ValidateTheAccountNumber()" />
>     </div>
> </form>
> ```

I wrote this script:

> function ValidateTheAccountNumber() {
>               return false;
>           }

I think, with this js function, the page can't postback.But it does.Please say me what is the wrong point that I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the result of the function call as well

```
... OnClientClick="return ValidateTheAccountNumber()" />
```